# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor Intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Downloaded and installed ASP.NET MVC 3 (final version) and still I do not have intellisense in Razor views? What is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Install the ReSharper 5.1.2 update and then ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor Intellisense will work again.

> ReSharper 5.1.2 doesn’t interfere with Visual Studio IntelliSense in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor syntax. Earlier ReSharper 5.x builds had certain issues with Razor IntelliSense that are addressed in 5.1.2. Specifically, ReSharper 5.1.2 doesn’t prevent Visual Studio from automatically providing its own IntelliSense in .cshtml and .vbhtml web pages anymore: both code completion and Parameter Info work as expected.

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/resharper-512-is-released/

Answer (score 2):

If you have R# installed, change the settings to use VS Intellisense instead of R#'s. R# does not have that capability for Razor yet. If you still want to use it you could try hitting the space bar after the period

Answer (score 0):

Are you up to date with service packs. Off the top of my head I think you need Visual Studio Service Pack 1 beta for it to work